# How to avoid writing browser cookies when running testcafe tests?

Tags: cookies, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am running the testcafe tests for a website. I want to avoid writing any browser cookies while running my testcafe tests. My website writes cookies but while running tests I want to avoid this. Is there any way to achieve this in testcafe?

Answer (score 3):

To disable cookies in the Google Chrome browser, follow these steps:

- Find the 'Preferences' file in the Google Chrome profile and specify `2` as the `profile.default_content_settings.cookies` key value.
- Specify the :userProfile flag after the browser alias.

```js
testcafe 'chrome:userProfile' /tests
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have no cookies at the start of a test, note that TestCafe automatically clears cookies before each test is started.

You can use [Role](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) if you want to clear cookies at some point of your test scenario, for example, if you want to authenticate as a different user.

If your scenario is more complex, take a look at [RequestMock](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/mocking-http-requests.html) and [RequestHook](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/creating-a-custom-http-request-hook.html) - they allow you to control any aspect of all requests and responses during a test session.

Comment: I want to block the cookies in chrome when I am starting testcafe. Chrome has a setting to block the cookie writing. Is there any way to start the testcafe with this browser setting.